How to deploy a finetuned model on a private server?
I have a project where I need to fine-tune a Large Language Model (LLM) such as LLAMA3 for a specific task and then deploy it on the company's server as a chatbot to recommend 'questionnaires / surveys' based on studies described by the users.
As I am new to working with LLMs, I need some guidance. Here is my planned approach:

Obtain a base model and train it on my dataset using a fine-tuning
method like QLoRa.
Save the trained model and convert it into a GGFU
file using LLAMA.cpp, allowing for local testing. (I'm planning to using langchain at this step)
Once the model is tested and verified, create an API that enables users to interact
with the model.
Develop a Docker image of the application, which
will consist of the API at this stage.
Deploy the API on the company’s private server using the Docker image and connect it to
our website.

Is this the correct approach to achieve my goal? Thank you for your help.

You have a fundamental but very common misunderstanding of what an API is. You confused it with a service.

would you mind explaining a bit more?

Simply said an API is the definition of a protocol. It is not a server or service, but services can implement an API. A typical way of "deploying" an API is to publish its documentation.
